# auto passing login credentials to a web form

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication

I have a webform that I'm trying to pass login credentials to. I'm uncertain if it's javascript based. But here is the code for the form. I want to able to pass the login credentials in the url or create some script to do the auto login. The form hides its action output so it doesn't make it easy. Please take a look. We have a new service where we don't want our users having to type that info thus saving a big headache.

Thank you.

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>
  <span>Your Username Or Email Address</span>
  <input type="text" class=" has-icon" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" maxlength="255">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" height="16" width="16">
  <path d="M1600 1405q0 120-73 189.5t-194 69.5h-874q-121 0-194-69.5t-73-189.5q0-53 3.5-103.5t14-109 26.5-108.5 43-97.5 62-81 85.5-53.5 111.5-20q9 0 42 21.5t74.5 48 108 48 133.5 21.5 133.5-21.5 108-48 74.5-48 42-21.5q61 0 111.5 20t85.5 53.5 62 81 43 97.5 26.5 108.5 14 109 3.5 103.5zm-320-893q0 159-112.5 271.5t-271.5 112.5-271.5-112.5-112.5-271.5 112.5-271.5 271.5-112.5 271.5 112.5 112.5 271.5z"></path>
  </svg>
  </label>
    <label>
  <span>Your Password<a tabindex="-1" href="/forgot">Forgot?</a></span>
  <input type="password" class=" has-icon" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" maxlength="128">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" height="16" width="16">
  <path d="M832 512q0-80-56-136t-136-56-136 56-56 136q0 42 19 83-41-19-83-19-80 0-136 56t-56 136 56 136 136 56 136-56 56-136q0-42-19-83 41 19 83 19 80 0 136-56t56-136zm851 704q0 17-49 66t-66 49q-9 0-28.5-16t-36.5-33-38.5-40-24.5-26l-96 96 220 220q28 28 28 68 0 42-39 81t-81 39q-40 0-68-28l-671-671q-176 131-365 131-163 0-265.5-102.5t-102.5-265.5q0-160 95-313t248-248 313-95q163 0 265.5 102.5t102.5 265.5q0 189-131 365l355 355 96-96q-3-3-26-24.5t-40-38.5-33-36.5-16-28.5q0-17 49-66t66-49q13 0 23 10 6 6 46 44.5t82 79.5 86.5 86 73 78 28.5 41z"></path>
  </svg>
  </label>
    <button class="submit">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" height="18" width="18">
    <path d="M1600 960q0 54-37 91l-651 651q-39 37-91 37-51 0-90-37l-75-75q-38-38-38-91t38-91l293-293h-704q-52 0-84.5-37.5t-32.5-90.5v-128q0-53 32.5-90.5t84.5-37.5h704l-293-294q-38-36-38-90t38-90l75-75q38-38 90-38 53 0 91 38l651 651q37 35 37 90z"></path>
    </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[code in formatted form - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNXJN.jpg)

Comment: First of all I think you should specify the name attribute inside input elements. Unless you set it with js, which I can't know.

Comment: again I didn't create the form. I'm trying to work around it.

Comment: Ok, most probably form is not going to work correctly, and is not that easy to work around it. Cause you don't know what variables the server expects to read from the GET request parameters. Is there any js code in the page? I'm asking cause this form is only going to work only if there is some kind of js mechanism handling login thing.

Comment: I was thinking a javascript could work to. If anyone has a good idea of how to do it, please I'm all ears.

Comment: Man in order for everything you've thinking to work, you first should understand how your browser (client) sends the authentication datat to the server. In order to do this you should also add on the question, any js code if there exist inside the HTML document, or any reference to js code held in its header fields